# How to disable the animation scrolling in a UIScrollView in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I loaded a pdf in a scrollview, and I would like to go directly to the next page without having the animation scrolling.

```
CGRect scrollViewRect = CGRectInset(viewRect, -scrollViewOutset, 0.0f);

theScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewRect]; // All
theScrollView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
theScrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
theScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO; 
theScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
theScrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
theScrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
theScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
theScrollView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
theScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
theScrollView.delegate = self;

[self.view addSubview:theScrollView];
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: is user able to scroll or you want to stop user interaction also?

Comment: I just want to remove the animation, the user is still able to interact. He can go to the next page, go to the previous, etc...

Comment: Have you check my answer ? is it working as expected ?

Comment: @Claudio you don't want scrollview bounce when data displaying is reach end right ?

Comment: @DarshanKunjadiya I would like that when the guy is swiping that it displays directly the next page without doing the animation scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use below method to jump on direct offset of your next page by below method.

```
[objUIScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(YOUR_X, YOUR_Y) animated:NO]

animated = NO;
```

If you are loading PDF through WebView than you need to follow below code:

```
webview.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(YOUR_X, YOUR_Y);
```

> Note : Use this above code in your Next Button page or after loading
>   `WebView` properly may be in below method.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
}
```

Hope this will work as you expected.

Comment: I try to put it in the Viewdidload, but it seems that it doesn't work. May be I have to check everywhere to be sure I don't change that values

Comment: so you want to jump on next page while PDF will load ? or you are trying something else ?

Comment: That exactly what I want, jumping on next page while swiping from the right to the left (like if I press in a "next" button to go to next page) without seeing the next page coming from the right to the left. I would like to see directly the next page.

Comment: so what you have done is load your PDF in web view right ?? or you are using `CGPDFDocument` ??

Answer (score 1):

Sure, simply use:

```
[theScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) animated:NO];
```

or

```
[theScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f) animated:NO];
```

and change the `CGPoint` or `CGRect` to the offset of the page of your liking.

Comment: I tried it, but it seems not to work, I always see the animation with the page goin' from the right to the left for example.